# Python ortools | Add Exactly 2 instead if AddExactlyOne

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I'm using `AddExactlyOne` from Python or-tools CP-SAT for the [nurses scheduling problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling#a_nurse_scheduling_problem).

(Using the `from ortools.sat.python import cp_model` code at the bottom of the link)

However, this code used `AddExactlyOne` to assign exact only one nurse in a shift. What I want to do is to assign exactly two nurses in a shift.

I tried:

`model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 2)`

instead of:
`model.AddExactlyOne(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses)`, which is already stated in the code.

However, no luck.
Any idea how to assign exactly two nurses in a shift? Something like: `AddExactlyTwo` instead of `AddExactlyOne`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the model.Add(sum() == 2) should work.

Comment: Is the `sum` in `model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 2)` a Python sum or the OR-Tools linear expression sum? What exactly happened when you try to use this constraint?

Comment: @LaurentPerron thanks for your reply .. but I’m already doing this as in my thread “ model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 2) ” .. can you plz elaborate? thanks

Comment: It does the right thing. Please define 'does not work'

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 2)
```

works correctly.

Unfortunately, the nurses scheduling problem is very constrained, and depends on the fact that `#nurses == #shifts`.

because of that assumption, any modification of the model will most likely create an infeasible model.

For a better model, please look at the [shift scheduling sample](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py).

Comment: Hello Laurent. Thanks for reply. Actually I tried num_nurses = 10 and
num_shifts = 2 and model.AddExactlyOne(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses), and it gave feasible solution. However, with model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 2) it doesn't give any feasible solution. Actually, I tried to alter number of nurses and shifts but again it works only with  model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)], Any advice, please?

Comment: As I said, the model is very brittle, and just meant to be used to showcase some API. For a real example, start from the shift scheduling code.